# Proving the median is less than the mean

Tags: systems-of-equations, average, median

I was given the following problem by a colleague who is studying for the GRE. The question, I believe, comes from a study guide.

> A rope is cut into five pieces of differing lengths. After the rope is
>   cut, the length of the longest piece is twice the average length of
>   the five cut pieces and is four times the length of the shortest
>   piece. Show that the median length of the five cut pieces is less than
>   the average length of the five cut pieces

I’ve racked my brain for a few hours and haven’t been able to show how the median piece length is less than the average piece length (which is obviously L/5 for a rope of length L). I was able to show that the longest piece has a length of 2L/5 while the shortest piece has a length of L/10. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When asking a question on Stackexchange, you should always provide more context to why you're asking the question and what you have tried. The people on this website are here to help you solve problems, not to do them for you. Asking questions in this way will often lead to them being down-voted and closed.

Comment: It's simple, find the mean and median of the lengths

Comment: @Hotdog Sorry. I’ve never posted a question here before. I was given the problem by a colleague who is studying for the GRE. (Apparently this was a problem in the study guide). I’ve racked my brain for a few hours and have not come up with an answer.

Comment: It's fine, and welcome to Stackexchange. I would reccommend editing your question to include the context that you have just provided if you have any hope of this question not being down-voted or closed. Also sharing any original attempts (however basic or futile) will help other users know where you are stuck and how to best help you.

Comment: @Tojrah the mean is simple enough: if L is the length of the rope then L/5 is the average length of the rope. From the problem’s description it can be shown that the shortest section of rope has a length of L/10. The longest section of rope has a length of 2L/5. As far as I can tell the median cannot be found with the information given. All that I can determine is a range for the median. Clearly the median is between L/10 and 2L/5.

Comment: The question should be: 'Show that the median length of the five cut pieces is *less or equal* ...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the rope is 100 units long and that it is cut into lengths $$m_1<m_2<m_3<m_4<m_5$$  The average length is $20$, so $m_5=40$ and $m_1 =10$.  Since $m_2>m_1=10$ and $m_4>m_3,$ we have $$100=m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4+m_5>60+2m_3\implies m_3<20.$$